# python 3 recursive function that prints in order

Tags: function, python-3.x, recursion

I want to print my list in order, but it keeps printing the first value

```
def print_order(s):
    if not s: 
        return
    print(s[0])
    print_order(s[:-1])
```

for example I have a list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] I want it to be
printed out as

```
    1 
    2 
    3 
    4 
    5 
    6 
    7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the last element off instead of the first.  Try changing the recursive call's argument to `s[1:]`.

Comment: @12345678 If this (or another) answer helped you, you can "accept" an answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The slice `s[:-1]` is all elements except the last.

You want `s[1:]`, which is all elements except the first.